# mod_wsgi WSGIPythonPath multiple paths on Windows

Tags: python, django, windows, apache, mod-wsgi

Windows 8.1 x64 - Python 3.4.1 (pyzo_distro-2014a.win64) - Apache httpd-2.4.10-win64 - mod_wsgi-3.5.ap24.win-amd64-py3.4

How to set multiple paths?
It seems only the last path is set.

```
WSGIPythonPath C:/test1;C:/test2;C:/test3
```

In Apache log file (with LogLevel info):

```
mod_wsgi (pid=3568): Initializing Python.
mod_wsgi (pid=3568): Attach interpreter ''.
mod_wsgi (pid=3568): Adding '(null)' to path.
mod_wsgi (pid=3568): Adding '(null)' to path.
mod_wsgi (pid=3568): Adding 'C:/test3' to path.
AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

Same result with:

```
WSGIPythonPath "C:/test1;C:/test2;C:/test3"
```

This doesn't work:

```
WSGIPythonPath "C:/test1";"C:/test2";"C:/test3"
```

because WSGIPythonPath accept only one argument.

Thanks.

Comment: : is the correct separator it seems.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to adding the directories using the WSGIPythonPath directive, you can instead add directories to path from within your code:

```
import sys, os
paths = ['C:\test1', 'C:\test2', 'C:\test3']
for path in paths:
    if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)
```

Or, if you need to add the current directory (not uncommon for Flask / Webapp2), you can place

You can place the following above your other imports in main.py:

```
import sys, os
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
```

Provided that your Apache server configuration looks something like:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /scripts "C:/web/wsgi_scripts/main.py"
WSGICallableObject app

<Directory "C:/web/wsgi_scripts">
<Files main.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```